# How to extract one item's index in python from a list?

Tags: python

I want to extract an index of just one item from the list

```
def main():
mylist = [21, 5, 8, 52, 21, 87]
num = input("What number: ")
if num in mylist:
    print(mylist.index(int(num)))
```

I tried this but it doesn't output like it should, it prints nothing.

Comment: num (the string) won't be in the list, you know this because you convert it to an integer before trying to get its index

Comment: `input` gives you strings; you need to convert them to ints first

Comment: Also... please indent properly

Comment: What do you mean it prints nothing? This should raise an exception... And it will make it easier if you cast to int from the start: `num = int(input(...))`

Comment: Yeah it says Process finished with exit code 0 ...

Comment: _I tried this but it doesn't output like it should, it prints nothing._ ..... _it says Process finished with exit code 0_ How is that possible? **That code leads to an exception.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to parse the input

```
if int(num) in mylist:
```

Now it'll work :)